# 2 overlays, end with all the overlays

Tags: beamer, overlays

I have the following code, with the result in a gif picture:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{About colors}
    \begin{columns}
    \column{0.5\textwidth}
    This is blue:
    \fcolorbox{black}{blue}{\hspace{2mm}}
    \column{0.5\textwidth}
    This is red:
    \fcolorbox{black}{red}{\hspace{2mm}}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

whereas what I want is the frame to end with showing the two columns:

[image]

How to do that?

Comment: The code example you included does not contain any code related to overlays, so I definitely get a different output than the one in your first gif. Please clarify.

Comment: What about `\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{About colors}
    \begin{columns}
    \column{0.5\textwidth}
    \only<1,3>{This is blue:
    \fcolorbox{black}{blue}{\hspace{2mm}}}
    \column{0.5\textwidth}
    \pause This is red:
    \fcolorbox{black}{red}{\hspace{2mm}}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`column` command is overalay aware, so you can indicate the overlays where you want to show each column:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{About colors}
    \begin{columns}
    \column<1,3>{0.5\textwidth}
    This is blue:
    \fcolorbox{black}{blue}{\hspace{2mm}}
    \column<2,3>{0.5\textwidth}
    This is red:
    \fcolorbox{black}{red}{\hspace{2mm}}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```